# Another depth first search in java issue

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am tying to implement a depth first search algorithm in java to find the best way to move in a quadratic matrix. I am avoiding to create "unnecessary" objects, i.e object just to hold (X,Y) positions.

Am I forgetting something? I am running it with starting points of (0,0) and with objective of (4,5). What happens is an infinite loop.

```
int x = this.move_to_x;
int y = this.move_to_y;

Stack X = new Stack();
Stack Y = new Stack();

Stack visited_X = new Stack();
Stack visited_Y = new Stack();

X.push(this.current_x);
Y.push(this.current_y);

while(!X.empty()){
    int tmp_x = (int)X.pop();
    int tmp_y = (int)Y.pop();

    if(tmp_x == x && tmp_y == y){
        System.out.println("best way found!");
        return;
    }

    //there is only 8 possible ways to go (the neighbors)
    for(int a = -1; a < 2; a++){
        for(int b = -1; b < 2; b++){
            if(a == 0 && b == 0){
                break;
            }

            if(visited_X.search(tmp_x + a) == -1 && visited_Y.search(tmp_y + b) == -1){
                X.push(tmp_x + a);
                Y.push(tmp_y + b);

                visited_X.push(tmp_x + a);
                visited_Y.push(tmp_y + b);

                System.out.println("added x " + tmp_x + a + " y " + tmp_y + b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect case for using a debugger ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several problems:

1) In the following:

```
        if(a == 0 && b == 0){
            break;
        }
```

you should be using `continue` rather than `break`.

2) The following:

```
if(visited_X.search(tmp_x + a) == -1 && visited_Y.search(tmp_y + b) == -1){
```

is incorrect: the `(tmp_x, tmp_y)` pair has to be present *at the same index* in `visited_X/visited_Y`.

3) You should add the starting position to `visited_{X,Y}`.

4) Algorithmically, I don't see any reason to think that your method would return the *shortest* path.

5) The reason your code ends up in (an almost) infinite loop is that you don't check for the matrix boundaries.

Comment: 4) You are right. I confused depth first search with breadth first search.